# What do you call a note that is "in" the given chord?

Tags: music

I'm trying to find a word that describes, for example, any one of the three notes in a C major chord. Would I just call it a "chord note"? Or is there a more fitting word or phrase to refer to that?

Comment: I've usually heard them called chord *members*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network ([Music](http://music.stackexchange.com), but that's not on the available migration paths)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't see why. This is a question about _English_ not music. The usage may be related to music but the question itself is not. The OP is not asking what a chord is but what the correct English word to describe a chord's notes is.

Comment: But a musician would have a better chance of knowing the nomenclature of their art.  Their are some musicians on this site but more on the music site.

Comment: It's not a question about English, because there are many English words, including "member", "part", just "note" or "note in the chord", all of which are reasonable and correct in their own way but only a musician can say what is *actually correct*.

Comment: Not sure why this question is considered off-topic as the question seeks an English term.  Such notes are often called in music theory _chord tones_.  In a similar fashion, notes that are not part of the prevailing harmonic structure of any given moment are called _non-chord tones_.  I'm happy to put this as an answer if this question can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in wikihow.com's *[Play Major Chords on a Keyboard](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Major-Chords-on-a-Keyboard)* article, a major chord has three particular notes, which are called *tonic, major third,* and *fifth*:

> A major chord has a very specific set of notes: the tonic, or root of the chord (0). This is the note that the chord is named after; the major third, which gives the chord its character (4 semitones above the root); and the fifth, which anchors the chord and makes it complete—7 semitones above the root.
>
> Every major chord has all three of those. In their most basic form, they are arranged as 0-4-7. For a C major chord, for example C is the tonic (0). Four semitones up from that is the major third: E. Three semitones up from that (or seven up from the root) is G.

Wikipedia's *[major third](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_third)* article explains the meaning of a third:

> a third is a musical interval encompassing three staff positions ... [a] major third is a third spanning four semitones ...

Slightly more generically, most major chords consist of *[consonant notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonance_and_dissonance)*.  Although not all sets of consonant notes are major chords, it might not be out of line to refer to the consonants of a chord.

Comment: Right. Now if I want to refer to them generically, the tonic, third, and fifth are all... whats? I want a name that refers to _any_ one of the notes in the chord.

Answer (score 1):

I would any of these:

> G is one of the notes that *form/make* up the C major chord.
>
> G is a *constituent* note of the C major chord.
>
> G is *one of* the notes of the C major chord.
>
> G is a *member* of the C major chord.
>
> G is *part of* the C major chord.
>
> G is *in* the C major chord.

Answer (score 0):

Since a note can be a ***component*** of different chords, I would just say, for example, "a C major chord is comprised of 3 notes, C, E, G. Or conversely, C, E and G are the three notes that make up a C major chord.

Comment: Well, then maybe "component note" would be correct?